# Подскажите, каким правилом объясняется запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, каким правилом объясняется запятая? Хорошо смеется человек — значит, хороший человек.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> *Хорошо смеется человек — **значит,** хороший человек.*

Разбираемое предложение одинаково часто пишется и с запятой, и без запятой. [**См. примеры.**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82,%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=YNWqWI65IIKgsgHJ973gCQ#q=%22%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82,%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)

И обосновать ссылками на разных авторов и разные правила можно оба варианта написания.

По Розенталю запятая в подобных предложениях ставится. [***См. "Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация", 2008:***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122,8#pp122)

> **§ 25...**
>
> Если слово ***значит*** находится между придаточной и главной частями
>   сложноподчиненного предложения и играет роль структурного элемента
>   предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: *Если наступит весна,
>   **значит,** будет тепло; Раз так упорно отстаивает свои взгляды, **значит,** чувствует свою правоту.*
>
> Если слово ***значит*** находится между частями бессоюзного сложного
>   предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: *Прозвенел звонок,
>   **значит,** урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, **значит,** пеняйте на самого себя.*

**ПАС** же в таких же предложениях рекомендует запятую после слова ***значит*** не ставить:

> [**§ 96.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127)  Многие из вводных слов и сочетаний слов могут быть омонимичны членам предложения или союзам. Такие различия (они
>   отражаются на пунктуации) проявляются в контексте…
>
> *На небе собираются тучи, **значит** будет дождь* (***значит*** — *союз*).

Первая редакция ***"Справочника по пунктуации"*** на *Грамоте.ру* придерживалась позиции, изложенной в ПАС:

> **ЗНАЧИТ**
>
> <...>
>
> 2. Союз. То же, что «и поэтому, следовательно». Соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного. **Запятая ставится только перед
>      союзом.**
>
> *Тучи собираются, **значит** будет дождь. Ты сердишься, **значит** ты не прав.*
>
> <...>
>
> Часть двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит». Запятая
>   ставится на стыке главного и придаточного предложения.
>
> ***Если*** встретиться нам не придется, **значит** такова наша судьба. Если я это сказал, **значит** я увлекся.

Ну а потом…

См. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3245

> **Редакция портала** » 29 июн 2012, 13:34
>
> Про слово ***значит*** и наш справочник.
>
> 1. Сначала оффтоп. Через какое-то время после того, как справочник по пунктуации был размещен на портале (под названием "Настольная книга
>      автора: Пунктуация"), авторы возобновили над ним работу, существенно
>      переработали и дополнили, добавили новые словарные статьи, уточнили
>      некоторые рекомендации.
>
> <...>
>
> 2. Теперь по теме ветки. Статья про слово "значит" для печатного издания была изменена (в электронной версии статья теперь тоже
>      обновлена и соответствует печатному изданию). Рекомендации ПАС
>      относительно союза "значит" сложившейся практике письма мало
>      соответствуют (достаточно обратиться к Национальному корпусу русского
>      языка, чтобы в этом убедиться). Союз "значит" на практике почти всегда
>      выделяется запятыми с двух сторон (как, собственно, написано у
>      Розенталя), поскольку сближается по значению с вводным словом. Поэтому
>      в справочнике по пунктуации теперь дана более привычная и более
>      соответствующая практике письма рекомендация: **союз значит отделяется
>      запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.**

Но такая позиция (выделение в сложных предложениях союза ***значит*** запятыми с двух сторон) рядом авторов не поддерживается.

Из словаря ***Остроумовой и Фрамполь "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений":***

> **ЗНАЧИТ**, союз:
>
> <…>
>
> 3. Невводное, употребляется в функции союза (= *следовательно*), соединяет части сложносочинённого предложения (с оттенком значения
>      следствия), **не обособляется**:
>
> *Тучи собираются, **значит** будет дождь; Ты сердишься, **значит** ты не прав; Все идут в эту сторону, **значит** там и клюква растёт* (М.
>   Пришвин).

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, автор хотел сказать: "Раз хорошо смеется человек — значит, он хороший человек" или "Если хорошо смеется человек — значит, он хороший человек". В обоих случаях слово "значит" выступает как союз, который соединяет части сложного предложения. [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220) указывает: "Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения."

Например: 
*Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит*. И. Тургенев,Живые мощи

Answer (score 0):

1) **Хорошо смеется человек — значит, хороший человек.** Это бессоюзное предложение (БСП), **основная связь** между предикативными частями является **интонационной**: восходящая интонация первой части, пауза, обозначенная на письме тире.

Вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ является **дополнительным структурным элементом** со значением следствия, при этом оно о**стается вводным слово и обособляется.** Поэтому при наличии тире ЗНАЧИТ обычно обособляется, невзирая на большое количество противоречивых правил: Послал он мне крест – **значит**, меня он любит.

2) Вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ может входить в состав двойных союзов в СПП: РАЗ...ЗНАЧИТ, ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ, в этом случае оно тоже обособляется.
**Раз** вы читаете это мое письмецо, **значит,** я вас уже покинул (СПП).
**Если** он не уезжает, **значит**, ему там нравится.

3) Вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ может образовывать **единое сочетание А ЗНАЧИТ, И ЗНАЧИТ в ССП,** запятая внутри сочетания не ставится: Однако на карту поставлено слишком многое, **а значит** попытаться стоит. Но для нее эти произведения живописи важны, **и значит** Ольга будет их покупать и привозить.

4) Проблемы начинаются, **если в БСП ставится запятая**, в этом случае ЗНАЧИТ начинают считать союзом и не обособляют. Но какой союз в бессоюзном предложении? Сравнить:  Юпитер, ты сердишься — **значит**, ты не прав. Ты сердишься, **значит** ты не прав.

Место, конечно, смутное,  и **большое количество запятых выглядит не лучшим образом.** Тогда можно считать, что ЗНАЧИТ выступает **в функции наречия** со значением следствия, **но только не союза**.